# angular 6 - send an API to child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a sample api to get a post by id, in my component i have an object config to send in the child component, this config  object contains the api to execute in the child component. When the the api execute in the child component i get an error in the httpClient

> cannot read property 'get' of undefined

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ugawmq)

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationAPI {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getPost(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id);
  }
}
```

**parent component**

```
  config = {
    columns: [
      {
        defaultValue: { dependFromAPI: this.api.getPost }
      }
    ]
  };
```

**child component**

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes["config"] && changes["config"].currentValue) {
      changes["config"].currentValue.columns[0].defaultValue.dependFromAPI("43").subscribe(item => console.log(item))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the function to the object property. One way would be to use arrow function notation

```js
config = {
  columns: [
    {
      defaultValue: { dependFromAPI: (id) => this.api.getPost(id) }
    }
  ]
};
```